# Finding the optimal arithmetic circuit for evaluating a given polynomial

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

The Horner's algorithm takes as input a univariate polynomial $f(X)$ and an evaluation point $x$ and computes $f(x)$ using $O(\deg(f))$ field operations.

Suppose now that the polynomial $f(X)$ is fixed. Is it possible to find an arithmetic circuit which is optimal for computing $f(x)$ (hopefully requiring a number of field operations sublinear in the degree of $f(X)$)?

Trivial example: For $f(X)=x^{2^n}$ there are only $n$ operations needed.

Comment: It’s surely *possible*. But if you actually want to ask whether it can be found by an efficient (say, better than exponential) algorithm, then no, no such algorithm is known, and likely does not exist.

Comment: Also, in case it is not obvious: while some polynomials such as $x^n$ have much smaller algebraic circuit complexity, most degree-$n$ polynomials have complexity $\Omega(n)$.

Comment: (The previous comment was meant to apply to polynomials over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$; more generally, it holds for any field of infinite transcendence degree over its prime field. For finite fields $\mathbb F_q$, the maximal algebraic circuit complexity of degree-$n$ polynomials is $\Theta(n \log q/\log n)$ or so.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek What's a good reference? I know of several references for the minimum circuit size problem (MCSP) in the case of Boolean circuits, but don't know much about the analogous problem for arithmetic circuits.

Comment: @TimothyChow I don't know of a reference specific to arithmetic circuits. But as far as I am aware, it is generally considered to be in a similar state as MCSP: the problem is likely hard, but its complexity is difficult to pinpoint exactly as it does not match better-known classes such as NP-complete.